# What is this integration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, integration, textbook-erratum

[image: screenshot]

This is from the book introduction to mechanics by Kleppner D.
Is it some typo, or something i don’t understand?
Does **F dt** comes down in front of integration?

Comment: Definitely a "bug" in the book typesetting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To me, this looks like a typo which should read something like

$$\underbrace{\int F dt}_{1\text{ collision}}$$

Comment: the "1 collision"  just looks like description of integral bounds, so I think it should be $\int_\text{1 collision} F dt$.